# В чём разница между =default и =delete внутри и вне класса?

Tags: c++, классы, delete, default

В чём разница между следующими объявлениями?

```
struct A {
  A() = default;
};

struct A {
  A();
};
A::A() = default;
```

Comment: Если они в разных файлах (в заголовке и в реализации), то в первом случае компилятору доступно больше информации - проще оптимизировать. Не надо напрягать компоновщик при компоновке.

Comment: `static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<A>); static_assert(not std::is_trivial_v<B>);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При объявлении внутри класса  `= default`, компилятор попытается сделать инлайн включение кода. Что даёт шанс уменьшить и ускорить код. Снаружи - код конструктора будет обязательно, для возможности вызова из других **.cpp** файлов.

Объявление `= delete` внутри класса и последующее использование функции вызывает ошибку компиляции сразу. Так как это указывает полное отсутствие кода. А если поставить в `.cpp` коде, то позже когда компилятор будет собирать проект будет уже ошибка сборки, что не найдена функция.